# Regular expressions not working in gulp-regex-replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

I'm trying to remove all line breaks in an HTML file using `gulp-regex-replace`. I'm trying the regular expressions [from here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/js+remove+line+breaks). None of them work.

```
let replace = require('gulp-regex-replace');

gulp.task("strip", function () {
  return (
    gulp
      .src("./*.html")
      .pipe(replace({regex:/\r?\n|\r/g, replace:''}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"))
  );
});
```

I also tried `/[\r\n]+/gm` with no luck.

Trying other regular expressions works, but line breaks don't budge. I'm using OS X with VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace).  `gulp-regex-replace` was last published 8 years ago and probably doesn't work well with gulp4.+.

I tested this with `gulp-replace` and it worked to remove newlines.

```js
const replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task("strip", function () {
  return (
    gulp
      .src("./*.html")
      .pipe(replace(/\r?\n/g, ''))       // simpler syntax too
      .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))           // this is probably enough for you
  );
});
```